# Recognizing Simplicial (Quasi)Fibrations

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, algorithms, simplicial-stuff, fibration

Let's say we are given two finite simplicial complexes, which I will suggestively call $E$ and $B$. We'd like an algorithm for the following decision problem:

> Does there exist a simplicial map $p:E \to B$ and a simplicial complex $F$ so that (**a**)
>   the inverse image $p^{-1}(\sigma)$ of every simplex $\sigma \in B$ is homotopy-equivalent to $F$, and moreover, (**b**) every inclusion $p^{-1}(\sigma) \hookrightarrow p^{-1}(\tau)$ where $\sigma$ is a face of $\tau$ is a homotopy-equivalence?

For those of you licking their lips at the prospect of constructing some awful word-problem type obstruction, please note that I'd also be delighted if one could answer the question above replacing all instances of homotopy with homology.

Comment: I suppose in general (the hard version of) your question is difficult.  For example, if $E$ and $B$ are $K(\pi,1)$'s your question is asking whether $E$ covers $B$ or not, which for the groups amounts to asking whether or not one group can be found as a subgroup of another -- the embedding problem for groups.   Although this is not what you're asking, if you were to go further and ask for a genuine fibre bundle, that is a very hard problem.  For high-dimensional manifolds there is a (difficult to compute) complete obstruction called the Farrell Fibering Theorem.

Comment: @RyanBudney, since he is asking for a simplicial map, I think it is not quite the same thing.  You could have that $E$ covers $B$ but that you have to do some subdivision to make the covering simplicial.

Comment: Sorry for being silly, but it seems to me that the homology part of the question can be solved by a stupid algorithm. Since everything is finite, you can enumerate all the simplicial maps, enumerate all the inclusions of simplices - and homology isomorphisms can be decided. My algebraic topology is not strong enough for anything slicker...

Comment: Another small point: I would probably prefer calling a map as in the question a quasifibration (as in the works of Dold and Thom). Fibrations are defined by a lifting property and it is quite rare that a map between finite simplicial complexes satisfies the full Kan lifting property.

Comment: Thanks for the various comments. I realize that the question might get hard: for instance, even the special case where $F$ is fixed to be a point requires testing whether a simplicial map realizes homotopy equivalence between $B$ and $E$. While various weaker versions could be "solved" by just enumerating all the simplicial maps, maybe there is something less expensive that one might be able to say in special cases.